# Can you install a .deb package while a .deb package is busy installing?

Tags: debian, dpkg, dpkg-buildpackage

I am creating a .deb package but I want to install a .deb package through the 1st installation.

So the 1st .deb package should install a .deb package. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to declare a dependency. [Here is the documentation from debian.org](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html), and this example comes from the docs:

```
For example, a list of dependencies might appear as:

Package: mutt
Version: 1.3.17-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.1), default-mta | mail-transport-agent
```